# Wordpress default stylesheet path

Tags: wordpress, templates, stylesheet

Is there any way to change default Wordpress stylesheet path? When I move style.css to /styles/style.css folder (and updating path in header.php) I cannot load my theme from admin panel, because WP screams about broken template :-/

I tried with `define('STYLESHEETPATH', get_template_directory . '/css');` in `functions.php` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* have a style.css in your theme folder since this is how WordPress identifies the theme, using the comments in the header of this file. If you wanted to host the actually CSS in a different subdirectory the easiest way would be to do a CSS import:

File **`style.css`**

```
/*  
Theme Name: My Theme
*/
@import url('css/style.css');
```

File **`css/style.css`**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
body { font-size:12px; }
```

You can also explicitly load both files, but I would recommend the way in the example above.

Changing the `STYLESHEETPATH` isn't recommend since many plugins use this to determine the active theme's path, however in your example you are missing the parens for the function call to `get_template_directory()`.

Comment: So rather than changing the STYLESHEETPATH maybe turning off check the style.css in root directory is possible then?

Comment: No, you cannot, as this is how WordPress gets the theme information.